# Not able to install Pymongo in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pymongo-3.x

I have used pip install pymongo but getting certificate verified failed . Is there any other way to install it.

Comment: Please show us the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use `pip install` as the comments mentioned `easy install` is depricated.

You can use `python -m pip install pymongo`.

Read further about pip and windows in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) stackoverflow post, they also offer different alterantives.

Comment: OP stated this he used pip in the past but he now was an issue with it, however i feel the linked questions can provide valid alternatives. also @Soumya i feel like solving your pip issue should be your priority as i'm sure you'll find it needed again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use easy_install from setuptools

```
python -m easy_install pymongo
```

or

```
python -m easy_install -U pymongo
```

or from the source

```
git clone git://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver.git pymongo
cd pymongo/
python setup.py install
```

Edit: it seems that easy_install is deprecated (ty for the comment), but it still in the pymongo doc...

Comment: Please don't use `easy_install`! It's been deprecated for a while now.

Comment: I didn't know that, this method is still in the pymongo doc. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .whl file for your Python version and architecture from https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/#files, then install it with e.g.

```
pip install pymongo-3.8.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```